# How to request a server and get response for android client

Tags: android, web-services, google-app-engine, restlet

I am a beginner to android and have designed a login GUI for app where a user will enter the login details. After fetching login details in java code (in strings) how can I pass it to server to check for a valid combination? Also when a new user enter registration details how can I pass it to server and store it in DB (MySQL DB)? What is the purpose of web service? Should I use web service or servlets (this is not the only thing later in my app I need to send contact details to/from server)?
I've read about SOAP and REST web services which one should I prefer? I would like to code in java for everything. Should (or can) I use Google AppEngine for server part? Am I supposed to create XML file of login details to send it to web service in case I use it?
A sample code could be of great help...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try separating your statements into blocks, its far easier to read.

Comment: What you are asking here is far too broad and wide-ranging for SO. You're essentially asking us to design an entire system for you. Try submitting targeted and well-scoped questions and you'll get better responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web Services are used for passing and performing operations in databases of remote servers. You can use JSON type for parsing data & sending data to server.

Take a look at [this link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)

Answer (score 1):

you can't connect to remote mysql database directly in android. You have to do this via [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html).